# Cannot access Guild id in slash commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making a slash commands bot and I'm trying to access the guild id in order to sync the commands but its not working. it gives me a NameError and that apparently guild id isnt defined, ive tried making it a global variable but it doesnt work either. I looked everywhere including stack overflow answer but couldn't find a solution for my type of code

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from credentials import TOKEN
from functions.dispatch_c import dispatch
from functions.ga_c import ga
from functions.nation_c import nation


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.guilds = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id))
        print("Tree Registered")

@tree.command(name = 'nation', description='Sends information about a particular nation', guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id))

async def nation_command(interaction, nation_name: str):
    await nation(interaction, nation_name)

@tree.command(name='ga', description='To see information about the General Assembly', guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id))

async def ga_command(interaction, proposal_id: int):
    await ga(interaction, proposal_id)

@tree.command(name='dispatch', description='To see information about a dispatch', guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id))

async def dispatch_command(interaction, dispatch_link: str):
    await dispatch(interaction, dispatch_link)
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/home/container/bot.py", line 26, in <module> @tree.command(name = 'nation', description='Sends information about a particular nation', guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id)) 

NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/bot.py", line 26, in <module>
    @tree.command(name = 'nation', description='Sends information about a particular nation', guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id))
                                                                                                                      ^^^^^
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the traceback

Comment: But the message is fairly explicit, `guild` is indeed not defined.

Comment: but how can i fix it, i have tried using a global variable and use it in all the commands, that didnt work either

Comment: It’s supposed to be your guild id, you don’t get the guild id from somewhere since this is where you want your commands to appear

Comment: but what if want to make a public bot, then I'd need to access the target server's guild id, which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really helpful but you can remove the `guild=guild` to have the command work on all servers, as it seems like that's what you were trying to accomplish.

to achieve that you must remove it on both `await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild.id))` and on all `@tree.command` you have. Also, You need to remove the for loop at `on_ready()`

here is the fixed code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")
    await tree.sync()

@tree.command(name = 'nation', description='Sends information about a particular nation')
async def nation_command(interaction, nation_name: str):
    await nation(interaction, nation_name)

@tree.command(name='ga', description='To see information about the General Assembly')
async def ga_command(interaction, proposal_id: int):
    await ga(interaction, proposal_id)

@tree.command(name='dispatch', description='To see information about a dispatch')
async def dispatch_command(interaction, dispatch_link: str):
    await dispatch(interaction, dispatch_link)
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```